# Adding Syslog is preventing stack corruption?

Tags: c, embedded-linux, syslog

We have a large codebase when a program crash is happening when the scale is high. The binary is an optimized one, so I could not see all the variables of the function from the core file. From the variables seen in the core, I could see that execution could not reach the point where the crash is happening. So I suspected stack corruption.

So to get some info I added some syslogs. After adding syslogs and multiple retries, the crash is not seen anymore with the same scale. So we suspected that syslog is adding some delay ( maybe a new I/O cycle) in the main thread and preventing the crash. So the crash may be due to race conditions between threads.

Now the root cause of the problem is identified and it is stack corruption and the issue is fixed.

Now coming to the question:
**I could not understand, how adding a syslog is preventing stack corruption?**
One clue is: The value printed using syslog is one of the variables that got corrupted (This variable is the reason for the process crash).

```
syslog() <<<<<< Printing the variable using syslog
Function call where the stack corruption is happening
Syslog() <<<<<< Printing the same variable using syslog
Memoryaccess of corrupted value() <<<<<<<<<<< Process crash
```

Comment: Classic [Heisenbug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug) and not at all surprising that adding code changes the stack or other data, thus changing the way that stack corruption or other errors affect the program. There are many ways this can happen. Adding a `syslog` call causes the compiler to bring its arguments into registers to pass to `syslog`. That changes how the compiler optimizes other things, so now it gets a variable from a register it is already in instead of from a saved location on the stack, or similar changes.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I completely agree with your answer. Bringing the variable to the register may be avoiding the crash. So stack corruption is still there. But the process crash is avoided.

Comment: I have one more doubt: The buffer overflow is only one byte, but I still see at least two variables in the stack are corrupted. Any pointers?